# Get the error code from Throwable - Android

Tags: android, error-code, throwable

How can I get the error code from the [Throwable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html)?

```
public void onFailure(Throwable exception) {

}
```

I saw that we can get the error messages, `LocalizedMessage`, etc.

Comment: What error code? Throwable has no such field

Comment: Please check the answer below

Answer (score 26):

Only HttpException gives you the HTTP error code. Make sure you check `instance of` before using it.

Here is the code:

```
if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
    HttpException exception = (HttpException) throwable;

    switch (exception.code()) {
        case 400:
            // Handle code 400
            break;
        case 500:
            // Handle code 500
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is the Kotlin version:

```
if(throwable is HttpException){
    when(throwable.code()){
        404->  // Manage 404 error
        else-> // Manage anything else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant [HTML error codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) like 500, 404, etc., you can use the following code snippet.

```java
if (ex.getCause() != null) // 'ex' is the Exception
    return ex.getCause().getMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```java
public void onFailure(Throwable exception) {
    Log.i("onFailure", "Throwable ", exception);
}
```

You try this.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [nhp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797634/get-the-rrror-code-from-throwable-android/44801103#44801103), but I didn't get the (exception.code()) option using the HttpException class, so I used the HttpResponseException class instead.

```
if (throwable instanceof HttpResponseException) {

    HttpResponseException exception = (HttpResponseException) throwable;
    eturn exception.getStatusCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the *retrofit2-rxjava2* adapter by Jake Wharton,

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

Then use:

```
if(throwable is com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException){ val code = throwable.code }
```