# How to retry in RxJava2 only when the response is a 404

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java2

I implemented a call using Retrofit with RxJava2 with retries, however I need it to retry only when you get a code different from 404. There's no point on retrying a 404. This is what I'm using

```
new RequestFactory()
    .requestBuilder
    .create(Service.class)
    .getData(id)
    .map(response -> response.object)
    .doOnError(t -> Log.e(NET, "Error fetching data id '" + id + "': " + t))
    .retry(3)
    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the other form of `retry()` to conditionally retry.

```
...
.retryWhen( error -> error.flatMap( responseType -> checkResponseType( responseType ) ) )
...
```

and then

```
Observable<Boolean> checkResponseType( ResponseException response ) {
  if ( response.getCode() == 404 ) {
    return Observable.error( response );
  }
  return Observable.just( Boolean.TRUE );
}
```

This will monitor the error response you get and check for the 404 value. If it is a 404, it won't retry, otherwise it will.

Comment: ResponseException is part of which import? rxjava2?

Comment: I only get an Observable<Throwable>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bob I managed to get something working using his response and this one ([Error code from Throwable - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797634/error-code-from-throwable-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)). Here's the final solution using Throwable. I removed the

```
.retry(3)
```

And I added Bob's suggestion. and the function being called was replaced to use a Throwable instead of ResponseException

```
private static Observable<Boolean> checkResponseType( Throwable response ) {
    if ((response instanceof HttpException) && ((HttpException) response).code() == 404) {
        return Observable.error(response);
    }
    return Observable.just(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```